# What is the better way of extracting values between <hr> tags using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've the following HTML which I'm scrapping using BeautifulSoup.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center">
        North America
        <hr>
        USA
        <hr>
        <font color="#990000">NYC</font>
      </td>

   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to extract and structure it like

```
{continent: 'North America', country: 'USA', city: 'NYC'}
```

I'm using the following method:

```
table = soup.find('table')
table.tbody.tr.td.text
```

And it gives me this:

```
u'\nNorth America\n\nUSA\n\nNYC\n'
```

Well this output is fine but I'm looking for some better way of solving it.

Comment: What does better mean?

Comment: Doesn't this way good?

Comment: @MohdAli, I think this [post](http://scraping.pro/extracting-sequential-html-element/) may give you some clues how to improve your scraper.

Comment: Well I'll have to do splits and other stuff like that. And secondly suppose there are other <td> which don't have any <hr>, then I've to use if conditions, etc.

Comment: @MohdAli try the code in my answer. It will give you the same results even if you remove those <hr> tags. Few lines, accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should install `lxml` and use BeautifulSoup with it: `BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')`. See [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for more information. It'll allow to fix incorrect `<hr>` tag. After that everything should work fine:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = '''<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center">
        North America
        <hr>
        USA
        <hr>
        <font color="#990000">NYC</font>
      </td>

   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

contents = soup.table.tbody.tr.td.contents
res = {
    'continent': contents[0].strip(), 
    'country': contents[2].strip(), 
    'city': contents[5].text.strip()
}

print(res)
# {'country': 'USA', 'continent': 'North America', 'city': 'NYC'}
```

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup sits on top of lxml. Use **`lxml`**:

> This code will work even if you remove those **`<hr>`** tags.

```
from lxml import html

text = """
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td style="vertical-align: top; text-align: center">
        North America
        <hr>
        USA
        <hr>
        <font color="#990000">NYC</font>
      </td>

   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
"""

tree = html.fromstring(text)

results = list()
for item in tree.xpath('//tr/td//text()'):
    [results.append(x.strip()) for x in item.split('\n') if x.strip() not in ""]

print results
```

**Output:**

```
['North America', 'USA', 'NYC']
```

And if you want a dictionary just:

```
print dict(continent=results[0], country=results[1], city=results[2])
```

**Output:**

```
{'city': 'NYC', 'continent': 'North America', 'country': 'USA'}
```